# Pesquisar no Banco de Dados

Tags: java, mysql

Estou em dúvida numa função de como fazer uma pesquisa no BD. Ele está indo para o catch. Alguém sabe dizer por que?  E como solucionar?

Essa é a função

```
public void consultar(){
    String sql ="select * from tbaluno where idaluno=?";
    try {
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         stmt.setString(1, textid.getText());
         rs = stmt.executeQuery();
         if(rs.next())

         System.out.println(textid);
         if(rs.next()){
             Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
             usuario.setNomealuno(rs.getString("nomealuno"));
             txtnome.setText(rs.getString(2));  
         }else{

         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

A mensagem que aparece quando eu coloco um id existente no banco de dados:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

EDIT-> Tabela MySQl, Contém:

ID  | Nome

1    | Vinicius

Queria que quando eu colocasse o id 1, mostrasse no campo nome "Vinicius".
A alteração que fiz na função consultar acima, foi apenas retirar um if e trocar o outro pelo while.

Comment: Não da pra saber, pois não tem como testar, todas essas variaveis dentro do try podem estar causando o erro, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel verificar a origem do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente em sua tabela existem mais coisas que `nomealuno` uma delas deve ser o `idaluno`, o qual vem antes.

Assim que o programa roda ele passa pelo único `if` eficaz (embora ali tenha um a mais) e não consegue acessar a coluna do nome, gerando um NULLPointer.

Experimente trocar o if por um `while(rs.next())` já que você seleciona todos os atributos no select. Ou mudar o select para só nome

Comment: Pra mim, isso já seria uma resposta.

Comment: Oi, editei como você falou, tentei explicar melhor. Continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: não compreendi a edição, você testou essa linha:
`if(rs.next()){` com `while(rs.next()){` ?

Comment: Não, testei assim não. Coloquei só o While(rs.next()) {.